# How to swipe a CollectionView with a fixed element

Tags: ios, calendar, uicollectionview

In the following animated gif you see a calendar (I guess is implemented as a collectionView) swiping left and right while the labels of weekday dont move at all.
Somebody has any idea of how is this accomplished?

[image]

Comment: It's very likely a UIPageViewController with a view on top where the day labels are.

Comment: Thanks @the4kman ! You are right indeed. Sometimes is very difficult to see an obvious thing.

Comment: Number of ways to implement above
1. Scrollview with paging: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/scrollview-with-paging
https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/scroll-view-paging-tutorial-ios8-swift
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html

2. CollectionView: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894834/uicollectionview-horizontal-paging-with-one-cell-at-a-time
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355226/create-a-paging-uicollectionview-with-swift
3. EIther use pagecontroller